# Are these marketing hacks good for poetry websites?

Tags: marketing, poetry, websites

I've got a couple of poetry websites and I would like to bring more traffic to them.

I have been thinking about exchanging links with other websites, for instance literary websites.

Are there other obvious and efficient ways to improve the visibility of a poetry website?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about writing

Comment: I think this is legitimately on-topic as a marketing question. I do however feel like more details could make it a *better question*.

Comment: I'm gonna vote to close for now but please keep in mind that this will only put your question on hold.  That is not a bad thing, it's a chance for you to rewrite it and make it a better question.  If you do that, I'll retract my vote.

Comment: This isn't about marketing it's about writers helping writers.

Comment: "The 10 poems that only romantic people know"  [yes, I've been practicing] :)

Comment: I edited your question. Please add more marketing things that you have considered. Also, revert the question if you think I completely changed its meaning.

Comment: Good edit @NofP.  The question is on topic now and I voted to reopen.

Comment: This might be more of a topic for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com where you will already find plenty of questions about how to improve the visibility and [search engine ranking](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo) of a website.

Answer (score 1):

Exchanging links with websites that you think are good, have useful info, etc. is a reasonable approach. I would not try a link exchange with a site that is a free-for-all, disorganized, and so on, because you want your site associated with positive, value-added experience. Email the owner of the site, provide your links, and ask if they are willing to do an exchange. This approach will help make you contacts with other writers and web site owners, in addition to exchanging links.

You may also want to look for sites where the writers blog and possibly find a way to guest blog on their site. That will also get you some views.